# How to create this mouse interaction using javascript?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, gesture, onmousemove, mousemotionlistener

The following link shows a sample: 
https://www.google.com/logos/2016/halloween16/halloween16.html

In this game the user needs to draw signs quickly with his mouse to defeat the approaching enemies. How I can detect these signs the user drawing with his mouse?

Comment: This seems like a generic thing, it is very difficult to help you here since you have not specified the problems you are facing with the implementation.

Comment: I would like to understand how the developers where able detect the mouse gestures, for example to detect a circle or a horizontal line

Answer (score 0):

You could use JCanvas. [https://projects.calebevans.me/jcanvas](https://projects.calebevans.me/jcanvas/)/ it works really well. Here is a demo: https://projects.calebevans.me/painter/

just strip the rest of the tools yo don't need.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't explain how the script detects the signs the user draws with his mouse on screen. There must be a possibility to detect those mouse movements.